# Push notification from marketing cloud to android app

Tags: push, appcenter

I am trying to send push notification from marketing cloud to android app as part of a POC.

I have tried the following steps:

> 1. Created google project and imported to firebase. Took the legacy server key generated in the firebase to create an app center application wherein Access token and AppID
> 2. Downloaded the Learning app and make appropriate changes to the android files(secrets.xml) and run the app on a physical device
>      connected via USB.
> 3. Created a contact in Marketing cloud(MC) with contact key(emailId), platform(Android),DeviceID(obtained from android studio logs), System
>      token(from Android studio logs).
> 4. Created a schedule push message using the application created in the app center and sent to a list which contains the contact imported in step 3.

But I am unable to receive any notification. The changes on android side are complete as on trying to send notification directly from firebase by making http request online, I am able to receive the notification.
There seems to be some sort of connection missing between app center and firebase.
Is there any way i can find/debug the connection between MC/App center and firebase.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Having the same issue here.